# how to write maximum likelihood estimation in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am beginner in Mathematica, and can only understand basic command so far. I need help in writing the maximum likelihood estimation function. I want to find the MLE of a Binomial distribution, with 2 parameters: n and p. I know that it is a quite simple one and actually I can get the answer manually, which I did. But I need to know how to write this in Mathematica to get the same answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[2, .3], 1000]; 
EstimatedDistribution[data, BinomialDistribution[n, p],
                      ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood"}]

(* -> BinomialDistribution[2, 0.3155] *)
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot! i used this code and it works. however, i get this message for my actual data: FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations. BinomialDistribution[4, 0.0252702]. Do you have any idea what has happened there?

Comment: @user1525225 You could try other methods described here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParameterEstimator.html. Form example `ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize"}]`